# How to model creation of resources using PUT according to the HATEOAS constraint?

Tags: rest, put, hateoas

Suppose I am developing a RESTful API with a container of items:

```
/items
```

and individual items would be identified by URIs like:

```
/items/{id}
```

What is the best way to describe the fact that new items can be created by PUT request under the HATEOAS constraint, i.e. where the client would specify {id}?

```
PUT /items/1234
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to describe the fact that new items can be created by PUT request under the HATEOAS constraint, i.e. where the client would specify {id}?

How would you do that on a web site?

You'd probably have some resource that provides a form; and the form would include the `id`, and possibly other interesting things.  The client would fill in the form (using semantic hints to interpret which information belonged in each field).  When the form is submitted, the HTML processing rules would encode the form values into an `application/x-www-url-formencoded` representation, which would become the query part of the target-url.  The server would review the payload, compute the appropriate target URI, and send a redirect response to the client.

The client can then GET/PUT/POST etc to the resource recommended by the server.

If you squint a little bit, you may see that the form is playing a role very similar to a [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).

So the basic sketch is pretty straight forward: the client and server have to agree on a media type that describes the template (and its semantic meaning), and the corresponding processing rules.

Here's the bad news: that bit is hard.  In the world-wide-web, HTML is doing a *ton* of the heavy lifting for us.  If your API is also using html representations of its resources, then you can piggy back on the forms that are already there.  But HTML has kind of fallen out of vogue.

In the API space, JSON has a lot of mind share, and there are a few media types that use it as a starting point.  [Sookocheff's 2014 survey](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/) is five years old now, but will give you some idea of what is out there.

Comment: Thanks, the form idea has merit, I'll think about that. I looked into RFC6570 templates and I like the idea of documenting links via Link: and Link-Template: headers and using OPTIONS to document the available HTTP methods, but I guess it's not possible to make HTTP requests (i.e. OPTIONS) on an RFC6570 URI template? Maybe Link-Template: with rel = URL to documentation (i.e. /rels/items/item).